# Waiting for a record in Oracle using python and take an action

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

In my first python project, I need to wait for a record to be inserted in an Oracle table. When the record is there, a python function should be called. I'm using cx_oracle.

The way I am doing it now, is to have an infinite loop and in the loop query the table. If the record is there, call the function. After wait for 5 seconds and start again. Something like this:

```
while 1:
  id = db.cursor.callfunc('FunctionThatReturnsID_OR_0_ifNoRecords', int)
  if id > 0:
    doSomething()
    delete_the_Record(id)
  time.sleep(5)
```

5 seconds is too much time and the system looks slow, but I don't want to overflow the database with queries every second. Is there any other way to wait for a record in python and do some action when the record is inserted?

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Advanced Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) is a way to go.

Comment: Thx. AQ is too complex for a simple problem like this, but I tried DBMS_ALERT.